# Size of colorbar ticks in seaborn.heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to change the size of the ticks of the colorer in my seaborn.heatmap. I'm not able to find something in the documentation. Can someone help me ?

Here is my Code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
ax = sns.heatmap(df_heatmap, linewidths=0.1, annot=True, ax=ax, cbar_kws={'label': 'Rel. $NV^-$ population'})
ax.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(15)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.xlabel("Probe laser duration [$\mu s$]", size=20)
plt.ylabel("Threshold", size=20)
plt.yticks(rotation=0) 
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `ax.figure.axes[-1].tick_params(labelsize=20)` ?

Comment: thanks, it is working !